# How to select multiple columns in Numbers?

Tags: iwork-numbers

In Numbers I have one column of values and in the next column I want to be values of the first column. I've got it to work with one column cell but when I select the whole column it gives an error.

Selecting one cell in column B:

[image]

If I select multiple columns or the whole column the New Function button is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks there are resize handles on the cell that when I drag up or down the formula is applied to the selected cells.

[image]